# Is there a way to remove quotation marks (Node.js Web Application)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Code:

```
async function watchAnime(episode_id) {

    res = await axios.get(`https://www1.gogoanime.cm/${episode_id}`)
    const body = await res.data;
    $ = cheerio.load(body)

    src=$('div.play-video > iframe').attr('src')

    iframe_result = src

    return await (iframe_result)

}
```

Output :

```
"//gogoplay1.com/streaming.php?id=MTU1MzEy&title=B%3A+The+Beginning+Succession+%28Dub%29+Episode+6"
```

[image: URL]

So its there a way to remove the quotation marks from the output URL??

Comment: Where exactly did the "output" come from?

Comment: This problem is not reproducible with the code shown.  Based on the comments below, you're probably just looking at the console output, which will always quote strings for you.  That doesn't mean there are quotes in the string data itself.

Answer (score -1):

To get a copy of a string `str` without its first and last character :

```
const newString = str.substring(1, str.length-1)
```

So :

```
const str = `"foo"`
console.log(str.substring(1, str.length-1)) // output foo
```

Comment: Thanks For Replying but i am unable to do that so can you please edit my code.. It would be grateful sir

Comment: It's not clear where your output comes from. Wherever it is, you could use my code to edit your string

Comment: Its nodejs so the output is on the webpage but after using your code the output is on my command prompt. Can i get the output on webpage??

Comment: you should show us your code that uses "watchAnime" , because we can't understand what you're asking with what you provided so far.

Comment: https://github.com/shashank445566/gogoanime-iframe-scraper have a loook

And you can check it by http://127.0.0.1:3000/getEpisode/b-the-beginning-succession-dub-episode-6

Comment: So line 43 of the app.js file, you use `res.send(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))` , where `result` is your url. Just apply my code before : `const url = result.substring(1, result.length-1)`, and then pass `url` instead of result : `res.send(JSON.stringify(url, null, 4))`

Comment: nothing happen bro

Comment: "/gogoplay1.com/streaming.php?id=MTU1MzEy&title=B%3A+The+Beginning+Succession+%28Dub%29+Episode+" 

This is the result "" dont get away but after " this gets

Comment: You can see the first and last character disapperead ("/" and "6"). So your result string is in fact `//gogoplay1.com/streaming.php?id=MTU1MzEy&title=B%3A+The+Beginning+Succession+%28Dub%29+Episode+6` , with no " .

Answer (score -1):

You may use `.replace()`

```
src.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

So in your case

```
async function watchAnime(episode_id) {
   res = await axios.get(`https://www1.gogoanime.cm/${episode_id}`)
   const body = await res.data;
   $ = cheerio.load(body)

   let src = $('div.play-video > iframe').attr('src')
   let iframe_result = src.replace(/['"]+/g, '')

   return await (iframe_result)
}
```

Comment: nope its not working it still gives the quotation marks...... Sorry for previous reply I by mistake replied you

Comment: can you show the example cases

Comment: "//gogoplay1.com/streaming.php?id=MTU1MzEy&title=B%3A+The+Beginning+Succession+%28Dub%29+Episode+6" 

It still gives as output

Comment: where di yo uput this src?

Comment: Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score -1):

You can try use **.replace function** like this :

```
const string = `i am' abc `;

console.log(string.replace("'", ''))
```

console :
i am abc

you can read more about is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)